# Wordpress's get_the_category( $id ) equivalent in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Basically I need something to return me the categories of an article. Joomla has multi level categories BUT articles can only reside in one of these categories. If the structure is like this:

- Fruits  (category id: 1)

  - Tropical (category id: 2)

    - Mango (article id: 1)
  - Seasonal  (category id: 3)
- Vegetables  (category id: 4)

I basically want an array of all ancestor categories. Meaning the Mango article will have an array of [1,2] returned with this function.

```
get_categories($aid=1) //will return [1,2]
```

I've looked into the Joomla API which is still being polished in this section. I was wondering if one of you had better luck. I haven't found anything on StackOverflow that will  help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get categories tree by using `JCategories` implementation for categories of component com_content.

```
<?php
jimport('joomla.application.categories');
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_content/helpers/category.php';

$articleId = $this->item->id;    // or your way to get articleId

$articlesModel = JModel::getInstance('ContentModelArticle');
$articleCategoryId = $articlesModel->getItem($articleId)->catid;

$contentCategoriesModel = new ContentCategories();
$categoryTree = $contentCategoriesModel->get($articleCategoryId)->getPath();
```

Important, that elements of result array will contains not only `id` of categories, but and `alias` field too (like a `2:tropical`). To extract integer `id` use `intval()` function like this:

```
foreach ($categoryTree as $categoryTreeNode) {
    $categoryTreeNodeId = intval($categoryTreeNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check and report back.

Comment: For some reason this is throwing an error at the `$categoryTree=` line, "Call to member function getPath() on a non-object"  What's the relationship between those last two bits of code and the code above it - they don't seem connected.  Thanks!

Comment: @Gisto it should be $contentCategoriesModel->get($articleCategoryId)->getPath(); not pass $contentCategoriesModel as was written.